# Convergence of a stochastic process of the form $\sum_{l=1}^n f_l(t) Y_l$.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, weak-convergence

Suppose $Y_1, Y_2, \dots $ are i.i.d. Bernoulli($p$) random variables, and $f_1, f_2, \ldots$ are uniformly bounded smooth functions. Consider a sequence of stochastic processes defined as follows:
\begin{align*}
F_n(t)  = \sum_{l=1}^n f_l(t) Y_l,
\end{align*}
where $t \in [0,1]$.

It is clear for every fixed $t$, $F_n(t)$ follows the standard CLT after normalization. I have two questions on this process:

1. Is it possible to show the convergence speed for $(F_n(t) - \mathbb E[F_n(t)])/\mathsf{sd}[F_n(t)]$ is uniform over $t \in [0,1]$?
2. Can we prove certain joint CLT for $(F_n(\frac 1n), \ldots, F_n(\frac{n-1}{n}), F_n(1))$?

Any reference/partial result will also be appreciated!

Comment: "It is clear for every fixed $t$, $F_n(t)$ follows the standard CLT after normalization." Why is it so clear? Even if the $f_\ell$ are deterministic, there are case where the CLT fails. Do you have other assumptions?